# Calculate div's width and distribute through images

Tags: jquery, image, width

Alright, what I have is a gallery where I want to insert several images. Some will be horizontal and others will be vertical oriented.

Now, if I had only horizontal images, I'd just set a width on the img tag and they all would fit perfectly like a grid.
[image]

Let's imagine the container width is fixed, like 1600px. Problem is that I'll also be inserting vertical photos. Let's take in consideration that horizontal are 1920px x 1280px and vertical are the other way around (1280px x 1920px).

Right now I've set in CSS that I want the image's width to be 500px, and it calculates the height, in order to appear like that in the grid. I can tell the height is being automatically calculated to 333px. Now, what happens if I insert a vertical image? This happens:

[image]

What I really wanted was that, through JS or whatever, vertical images would go for the 333px as the width, since it's the other way around, but still, I'd have another problem:

[image]

There would be a gap. Is there a way to create a script so that the page can calculate the widthts and display the photos in something like this:

[image]

Obviously the first pictures next to the vertical picture are bigger - no problem at all!

HTML

```
<div id="photos">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#photos {
    width: 1600px;
    float: left;
}

#photos img { width: 500px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bunch of existing scripts specifically for that purpose.

The most well-known is [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), but not necessarily the best out there.

The one i like the most is [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/). It allows laying out your grid via CSS, thus not violating the separation of concerns principle.

Comment: I've tried Masonry and also Isotope but they're a bit confusing, and I'm a little noob too. I've tried Salvattore just now but I think it won't work because the problem is that the image tags are generated automatically and I can't really separate them into columns. However here's what I was doing http://jsfiddle.net/bxhsg1kz/

Comment: Actually I think I was doing it wrong. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bxhsg1kz/1/

Though the sizes are not really working.

Comment: Considering the horizontal images are 200x120, the vertical should be 120x200, which is the other way around. Instead, they're applying 200 as the width aswell since the columns are defined to work that way.